# How can I connect to MySQL from behind a firewall?

Tags: c#, mysql, firewall

For school I need to make a C# application which uses a MySQL database as backend. The only thing which is stopping me from doing that is the big firewall of our school blocking everything except HTTP traffic on Port 80.

Hosting the MySQL database on port 80 is not an option, because that's still no HTTP traffic.

Does anyone know a way in which I can still connect to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just install a MySQL server locally and use the loopback address, in that way you don't need to access an external server.
I like using wamp, it's an Apache, PHP, MySQL server all in one.

Comment: The application has to be able to run multiple clients on different machines. Is that possible with a localhost *AMP?

Comment: You can open your Computers' firewall to allow incoming connections to your MySQL server (just 'go online' with wamp). You should be able to access the server on a local network without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Create a web service which will be accessed via port 80 and use that web service to access database.