# Connect MySQL database behind firewall

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

There is a server I wish to connect to. It has multiple VMs running on it each VM has a mysql DB. I can currently connect to this server using ssh and then connect to any of the databases from each VM using `mysql -u user -h host -p password`. Now I want to connect to the same MySQL DBs using MySQL workbench from my local machine. However there is firewall, currently I use putty to get passed the firewall with public private key authentication and I can access any machine I want.  I have seen  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124094/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-behind-a-firewall)  that I must install a MySQL server locally ( I've done this I am using mysql workbench) and use the loop-back address, in that way you don't need to access an external server. Could anyone point in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ssh tunnelling.

In putty under the options go to Connection->SSH->Tunnels. Add a tunnel from source port `13306` to Destination `localhost:3306`.

You can do this in Putty either before or after you connect. It's best to do beforehand and save the session configuration otherwise it gets tedious having to re-enter the settings.

In MySQL workbench connect to `localhost` port `13306`.

There is a good guide with screen shots here: [Setting up an SSH tunnel with PuTTY](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html)

An SSH tunnel makes a TCP port on your SSH client machine and directs any traffic to whatever the destination is set to. You can add multiple tunnels, but each one must listen on a different source port number.

Comment: I've created tunnels before be problem thanks! I'm a little confused, I create the port 13306 to destination localhost:3306. Why do I specify localhost? Sorry I just am trying to learn why I'm doing it just so I can understand it better.

Comment: In your question you said you had installed MySQL locally. This would be using port 3306 already so you need to tunnel a different one. Any number between 5000 and 65535 is usually free. What is important is that the source port number determines the one that MySQL workbench connects to in order to be tunnelled to the specified destination.

Comment: Just so I'm clear I have currently a connection set up to by pass the firewall on putty. Now there are multiple VM's with mysql DBs. I have to create a tunnel to each of these DBs. Why do I not have to specify the IP address of each of the VMs for the MySQL DBs?

Comment: Each tunnel specifies one destination. So use multiple source port numbers on a single SSH connection - consecutive numbers are fine. The destination for each tunnel will be a a single endpoint - a single MySQL DB on an IP and port 3306. What you effectively is create a map between source ports on your local machine and IP address destinations for each MySQL host.

Comment: Ok that makes thank you. I have my Putty session set and I can get my firewall. In putty I use ssh user@192.1.1.00 to connect to the VM and then mysql -uuser -ppasswrd to connect tot the MySQL DB. For my tunnel should I specify the destination @ 192.1.1.00:3306 and a source port of 13306? I've tried this it did not work but should it?

Comment: It should work. Can your SSH server (The one you connect to with putty) connect to MySQL on the VM? e.g. On the SSH server, try mysql -uXX -pXX -h 192.1.1.00 and see if it connects to MySQL.

Comment: No it can't Damn it! I'm getting this error ERROR 1251: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Answer (score 1):

You can forward the port via SSH.

ssh -NL is your friend like so:

`ssh -NL 3306:localhost:3306 <yourserver>`

Then you can point your workbench at localhost.

Comment: where do I write the command ssh -NL 3306:localhost:3306 <yourserver> do I specify it on workbench? I'm currently using windows.

Comment: @TrevDred Same place place where you connect to your server using SSH (I assume cmd/putty). While that runs, connect to localhost using workbench.

Comment: I've used ssh -NL 3306:localhost:3306 user@192.111.0.00 afterI've connected to the putty. The VM is password protected when I enter the password  prompt just hangs. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @TrevDred, it's supposed to "hang". While it "hangs", the tunnel is open. Go ahead and connect with Workbench.

Comment: If you just read my answer or the comments, the answer is there. It's localhost.

Comment: channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3306
Could not request local forwarding.   I'm getting this message now?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any additional software for this task. MySQL Workbench can create SSH tunnels on its own. Watch my tutorial on Youtube how to create connections: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY.

It essentially comes down to creating the right connection type. There is a drop down that allows you to select an SSH connection. Enter the parameters which you used to connect via Putty.

[image]